# Какие методы существуют в ReplyKeyboardMarkup

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

pyTelegramBotAPI

Знаком с inline кнопками, решил глянуть reply.

В inline есть callbaсk_data, с помощью неё мы можем узнать чего хочет пользователь.

```
types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обо мне', callback_data='about')
if call.data == 'about':
    делаем что-то
```

А в случае с reply, можно узнать что запросил пользователь только с помощью текста.

```
start_menu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
start = types.KeyboardButton('Как дела?')
start_menu.add(start)

if message.text == 'Как дела?':
    делаем что-то
```

Почитал документацию, но не нашёл других методов получения значения из кнопки.
Может кто-то знает, как получить значение, с помощью чего-то другого, вроде callback_data?

Comment: Так в этом их разница и есть. Единственное, что нужный текст для реплаев нужно в хендлер передавать

Comment: @clark-devlin, не совсем понял, условно у меня есть две кнопки "Как дела?", как мне прописать отдельное действие для каждой?

Comment: Для реплая просто нагородить кучу других реплаев перед этим.

Comment: @SaNoKProG ну так реплай клавиатура просто заставляет юзера вписывать текст который написан на кнопке, по факту ты должен его обрабатывать как обычное сообщение от пользователя. Поэтому если ты сделать две кнопки с одинаковым текстом, то нужно сделать мессежд хендлер который реагирует на текст кнопки. (Само собой смысла делать две кнопки с однинаковым текстом нет)